# In static template, script tag to import another file not working

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I have created `Field.js` and `index.js`. `index.js` uses Field. However `Field.js` is never loading. My sandbox is below.

Is it not possible to do `<script src="Field.js"></script>` in codesandbox? Does it only work for `src="index.js"`?

Here is my sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/l55933j36z

[image]

Comment: Does the other scripts load? And if, how do you know the `Field.js` doesn't?

Comment: Be aware that many browsers of today load stuff in parallel, so the `Field.js` might not be fully downloaded when `index.js` tries to access some of its content

Comment: @LGSon thanks for asking - the only file that loads is index.js - all others don't. It's mind boggling. I know `Field.js` is not loading because I put an alert in there, and also a DOMContentLoaded event to console log.

Comment: Hmm, I just ran that Sandbox and got the "Field loaded" alert...using Chrome

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm using Firefox. I'll trouble shoot it, thanks @LGSon

Comment: Noti I would consider using a custom event here, have Field.js dispatch the event. 
Dependant scripts can listen. Want me to post a simple demo? Also documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Given that the issue was a typo, I recommend you vote to close as such, or simply delete this post, as it has no value for future users.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon - deleting now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how we might listen for a custom event. This would allow you to 'wait' for the script and function correctly.

```js
// This lives in you scrip dependancy.
const scriptReadyEvent = new CustomEvent('MyScriptLoaded', {
  bubbles: true
});

// Dummy a delay in loading a script
function demoDelay() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('foo');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// Listen for script loaded
document.addEventListener('MyScriptLoaded', () => {
  console.log('Script is loaded');
});

// The script would do this.
demoDelay().then(() => {
  document.dispatchEvent(scriptReadyEvent);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bibberty I upvoted this, but the probem is unrelated. I upvoted though for your effort. I actually had a typo in the Field.js file which was stoping it from loading haha

Comment: Sorry, my bad just read whole Q and then looked at screen shot. It looked like `<scr1pt>` was that the real issue? Anyway, glad your back in action. Thx

Comment: Thanks @Bibberty - the real issue was inside there was a typo bug. So it was stopping it from loading. May you delete your solution please so I can delete the topic? Thanks!